# Can't Change Buddypress Language

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I've tried too much for changing the language of buddypress but failed.

I have set the language in wp-config.php

```
define('WPLANG', 'es_ES');
if ( file_exists( WP_LANG_DIR . '/buddypress-es_ES.mo' ) ) {
    load_textdomain( 'buddypress', WP_LANG_DIR . '/buddypress-es_ES.mo' );
}
```

Nothing worked. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

That code should be good. Why the if statement when `define('WPLANG', 'es_ES');` should work properly? BuddyPress follows the language settings set by WordPress.

Verify you have the translation file uploaded via:

wp-content/languages/themes/your_theme-es_ES.mo

Also, note that if you're using WordPress v4.0 and above you can change the language in the dashboard (assuming you have the language files) via Settings > General > Site Language.